# How to instantiate and return a wrapped C++ object from AsyncWorker

Tags: c++, node.js, node-addon-api

I'm following the Node Addon API documentation to resolve a promise on the C++ side. On resolve I'd like to return a C++ object back to JS. My code is similar to what is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/issues/85#issuecomment-555864757). The main difference is that I'd like to return an instance of the object below, which is `Napi::ObjectWrap`'ed:

```cpp
class MyWrappedObject final : public Napi::ObjectWrap<MyWrappedObject> {
public:
  static Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {} ;
  MyWrappedObject(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) : Napi::ObjectWrap<MyWrappedObject>(info) {};
}
```

i.e. in the async worker I'd like to resolve like so:

```cpp
void OnOK() {
  const auto wrapped_object = MyWrappedObject();
  deferred.Resolve(Napi::Object::New(Env(), wrapped_object));
}
```

the issue here is that the ctor for `Napi::ObjectWrap` requires a `Napi::CallbackInfo` as argument but the context during the `OnOK` call doesn't provide that callback info. So I'm wondering what am I missing here, I've read the documents but cannot find any examples where they return a wrapped c++ object from a promise.